# create an array of strings from an RSS feed

Tags: c#, ios, string, rss, xamarin

Is there an easy way to create an array of strings from an RSS feed using c#?

I am current statically creating an array using:

```
string[] tableItems = new string[] {"Item 1","Item 2","Item 3","Item 4","Item 5","Item 6"};
```

But I would like this to ultimately come from an RSS feed in the web.

This is going to be used to populate a UITableView in a Xamarin iOS project... So any suggested better practices are welcome.

Thanks, Guy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work.  This is just basic LINQ, nothing Xamarin specific.  Note that you might need to tweak depending on your flavor of RSS.  Also, instead of just extracting strings you could also build a domain object to represent an item and build a list of items instead.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("http://url_for_feed/feed.rss");

List<string> items = (from x in doc.Descendants("item") 
     select x.Element("title").Value).ToList();
```

Comment: I think I need to tweak slightly for the Xamarin implantation of the Linq class - but you have pointed me in the right direction. Thanks, Guy.